Expectation of bessel process conditioned on starting point
I want to calculate the expectation of the Bessel process for $n=3$
$$\begin{align}
dX_t = dW_t + \frac{1}{X_t} dt
\end{align}
$$
given that we start at initial point $X_0=1$.
My attempt was the following:
$$\begin{align}
E[dX_t] = dE[X_t] + E[\frac{1}{X_t}]dt
\end{align}
$$
to arrive at some deterministic differential equation for the mean. This works well for instance for the OU process. However, we have the problem of the fraction in the expectation. I would be happy about and hints how to solve this.
I am aware that the Bessel process is not defined for $X_t = 0$; however, I want to work in the setting where this does not happen (e.g. conditioning on not hitting 0).
Simulations show the following:


Wikipedia says that if $B$ is standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $X_t = |B_t|$ solves the SDE. Since $B_t$ is multivariate normal, $E(|B_t|)$ should be well known.

You will have to compute the mean of $X_t$ through its distribution. Yet, Bessel processes are known to be $\chi$-distributed mutatis mutandis.
